# How to use . and -> in program when referring the variable from a class

Tags: c++

I am new to programming in c++.Can you please explain (with example if possible)  in which case . and -> have to use when accessing variable from a class

Comment: Please pick up one of our [recommended books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Comment: In light of all your comments, you shoud clearly follow John's advice of reading a good C++ book.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions.Sorry for my poor question.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have pointer use `->` if you have object or reference use `.` e.g. Say I have:

```
class foo{

public:
    int a;
}

int main()
{
    foo f;
    foo* f1 = new foo();
    cout<<f.a<<"\n"<<f1->a<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: can you please explain with example

Comment: @Rama:  The answer provided by deeiip is exceedingly clear.  Examples are always nice, but if you can't understand this answer then you'd probably be better served by studying a good C++ book first.

Comment: I can only approve the advice of reading a good book.

Answer (score 1):

`::` is the *scope resolution operator*, used for referencing static class members and namespace elements.

`->` is the ***indirect*** reference operator, used for referencing members methods and fields on an instance pointer.

`.` is the ***direct*** reference operator, used for referencing member methods and fields on an instance.

Comment: how can i  assign varibles in a class so that i can access those variables with these operators in another class

Comment: You need to follow a tutorial first if you're going to ask that kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer type and you want to access a member object or member function you can use `(*ptr).anything` or `ptr->anything`. In most cases that's exactly the same (unless of course a specific `->` operator is overloaded). If you have a non pointer type you should use `.`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, these both operators are used by an instance to access members or methods.

`.` is used by **instance** or **instance reference**

`->` is used by **instance pointer**

In Example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int a;
}

int main()
{
     // Instance, Reference, and Pointer declaration
     MyClass instance;
     MyClass& instanceReference = instance;
     MyClass* instancePointer = new MyClass();

     // Usecases
     int a;
     a = instance.a;
     a = instanceReference.a;
     a = instancePointer->a;
}
```